# iPhone downloading not working

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

I've been trying to download apps from the App Store since last night.  I continually get messages saying the download can't be completed.

Comment: Are you connected to wifi? Can you download something not from the app store, like a PDF from Safari? Please respond with `@JohnRamos`.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your phone?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd do is do a hard restart of my phone (hold the power and home buttons down for about 10 seconds - wait for the screen to go black then for the apple logo to appear). If that doesn't do it, try signing out of the app store, and then signing back in.